# Why is Bootstrap typeahead not working for input elements with same ID?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML structure is like this :

```
<div class="controls">
<input id="car" class="span3" type="text"  placeholder="B.E" autocomplete="off" value="" name="car[]">
</div>

<div class="controls">
<input id="car" class="span3" type="text"  placeholder="B.E" autocomplete="off" value="" name="car[]">
</div>
```

My javascript is given below:

```
car = getcar();
$("#car").click(function() {
$('#car').typeahead({
    source: car,
    items: 10
});
});
```

`getcar()` is function which is getting source data using `ajax`

It is showing typeahead for only first `input` element not for second `input` element

What should i do now?

Comment: First and foremost, you shall not have two elements with the same ID, ever.

Comment: ID : Method of uniquely identifying a thing. Therefore, if you use the same ID more than once (in anything), it'll go horribly wrong.

Comment: actually i generating above `input` element dynamically .IF i generate `input` element id as `car[]` then how should i write my javascript to generate source data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few points that may cause your problems.

### Ajax call

There is no way you can get data from an ajax request by simply calling `data = getData();`.

You have to use callbacks, you can check the basic examples on the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples)

### Duplicate IDs

HTML element IDs must be different on the same page. Check the [w3.org doc](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Attributes/_Global#Core_Attributes). Instead you could use classes like `<input class="car" ...` and the jQuery selector `$('.car')`

### Typeahead initialization

The Typeahead plugin should only be initialized once. If you bind some event to activate the plugin, then you should unbind this event so that it isn't called again.

---

Here is an example that you could adapt to your situation, with its [working demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/p3wXs/)

```js
$('.typeahead').on('click.typeaheadonce', function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.off('click.typeaheadonce'); // Disable this listener so that it's called only once
    $.ajax(ajaxUrl, {
        type: 'post',
        data: ajaxData
    }).done(function(data) {
        // initialize the typeahead plugin
        $this.typeahead({
            source: data
        });
        alert('activated!'); // Ok !
    });
});
```

Based on the markup

```html
<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
<input type="text" class="typeahead" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to uninitialize the tyeahead plugin, or change the contents of the source in some way..?

Comment: Look around, like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9477095/1478467) or [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[twitter-bootstrap]+typeahead+source+modify) but it has already been answered.

Comment: I don't get the solution to many $this for it to me. I can't follow that but I now it works on jfiddle. What would you put instead of this?

Comment: `$this` could be changed to `var $typeaheadInput = $(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same ID twice. Try this (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
<div class="controls">
<input id="car1" class="typeahead span3" type="text"  placeholder="B.E" autocomplete="off" value="" name="car[]">
</div>

<div class="controls">
<input id="car2" class="typeahead span3" type="text"  placeholder="B.E" autocomplete="off" value="" name="car[]">
</div>
```

javascript is given below:

```
car = getcar();
$(".typeahead").click(function() {
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: $(this),
    items: 10
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a dynamic DOM so, i use this:
For each new element, i give a random id, then activate typeahead on this element, by id

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".typeahead", function() {
  if( $(this).data('autocomple_ready') != 'ok' ){
      $(this).attr('id',Math.round(new Date().getTime() +(Math.random() * 100)));
      var assigned_id=$(this).attr('id');
      $('#'+assigned_id).typeahead({
          hint: true,
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 4,
          delay:500,
          source: function (query, process) {
              return $.post('put_your_url_here',{ 'query': query },
                  function (data) {
                      return process(data);
                  },'json');
          },
          displayText: function(item){ return item.name;}

      });  
    };
    $(this).data('autocomple_ready','ok');
  });
```