# Twitter bootstrap typeahead works only for the first element on the page

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using typeahead for several elements on my page, but it only works for the 1st one and doesn't for the rest of them, although their data source is generated in absolutely same manner and has all the right values (data-source="["abc","cbd"]").
Does anybody know why it happens?

Thank you

Comment: this may help- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123885/why-is-bootstrap-typeahead-not-working-for-input-elements-with-same-id

Comment: Thanks for the comment! i've changed the <option> name to be different, it didn't help. I'm using php, not javascript.