# How to call live or bind event on typeahead function

Tags: jquery

This is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".type", this).typeahead({
            source: function(type, process) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?option=com_las&task=client.gettype",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "type=" + type,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        process(data);
                    }

                });

            }
        });
    });
```

how can i call a live event in this case for runtime generated field.........

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the data of the typeahead after its initialization too. The code will be something like this.

```
 jQuery(".type").typeahead();
```

Now  we can make the AJAX call and bind the data

```
   jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_las&task=client.gettype",
    type: "POST",
    data: "type=" + type,
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {


        //NOTE: You have to create a new array object and store values in it and then pass it as source

        var dataArray = [];
        for (var i in data) {
            dataArray.push(data[i]);
        }


        $(".type").data('typeahead').source = dataArray;
    }

});
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477095/trouble-updating-bootstraps-typeahead-data-source-with-post-response) for more info.

Comment: did the answer help you?