# Does twitter bootstrap typeahead supports remote data source?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Does typeahead feature support remote data source in version 2.0.3 of twitter-bootstrap?

The link to typehead functionality  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: "source : array". I think you have to build the array yourself. (BTW JQueryUI Autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote.html) allows JSON as source file)

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example

Comment: go with autocomplete jquery-ui, it's more more simple to use.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, typeahead) {
        return $.post('/typeahead', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return typeahead.process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but only if the arguments for the function were reversed in order: function (query, callback) instead of (callback, query).