# twitter bootstrap typeahead (method 'toLowerCase' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, typeahead

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap to get the manufacturers from my DB.

Because twitter bootstrap typeahead does not support ajax calls I am using this fork:

https://gist.github.com/1866577

In that page there is this [comment](https://gist.github.com/1866577#gistcomment-307488) that mentions how to do exactly what I want to do. The problem is when I run my code I keep on getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

I googled around and came tried changing my jquery file to both using the minified and non minified as well as the one hosted on google code and I kept getting the same error.

My code currently is as follows:

```
$('#manufacturer').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+"/bows/get_manufacturers.json",
            type: "POST",
            data: "",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false,
            success: function(results){
                var manufacturers = new Array;
                $.map(results.data.manufacturers, function(data, item){
                    var group;
                    group = {
                        manufacturer_id: data.Manufacturer.id,
                        manufacturer: data.Manufacturer.manufacturer
                    };
                    manufacturers.push(group);
                });
                typeahead.process(manufacturers);
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'name',
    items:11,
    onselect: function (obj) {

    }
});
```

on the url field I added the

> window.location.origin

to avoid any problems as already discussed on another question

Also before I was using `$.each()` and then decided to use `$.map()` as recomended Tomislav Markovski in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example/11147113#comment14731742_11147113)

Anyone has any idea why I keep getting this problem?!

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to debug the JavaScript code using Firebug or IE's F12 Developer Tools to find exactly where it's trying to call `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @Cory using Google Chrome Inspect tool I get that the error is on the twitter bootstrap code line 1664 
Equivalent to line 124 on the [fork](https://raw.github.com/gist/1866577/dd58c66be9dcb5b770e7f51a6cff324bec856021/bootstrap-typeahead.js)

Comment: @mmoscosa in Chrome Developer tools many javascript errors have a dropdown with other errors inside and one of those errors is the line in your code where that error comes up. The error is associated with something in bootstrap, but where the error actually comes up is in your own code.

Answer (score 10):

Typeahead expect a list of string as source

```js
$('#manufacturer').typeahead({
    source : ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
})
```

---

In your case you want to use it with a list of objects. This way you'll have to make some changes to make it works

This should works :

```js
$('#manufacturer').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+"/bows/get_manufacturers.json",
            type: "POST",
            data: "",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false,
            success: function(results){
                var manufacturers = new Array;
                $.map(results.data.manufacturers, function(data){
                    var group;
                    group = {
                        manufacturer_id: data.Manufacturer.id,
                        manufacturer: data.Manufacturer.manufacturer,

                        toString: function () {
                            return JSON.stringify(this);
                        },
                        toLowerCase: function () {
                            return this.manufacturer.toLowerCase();
                        },
                        indexOf: function (string) {
                            return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this.manufacturer, arguments);
                        },
                        replace: function (string) {
                            return String.prototype.replace.apply(this.manufacturer, arguments);
                        }
                    };
                    manufacturers.push(group);
                });
                typeahead.process(manufacturers);
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'manufacturer',
    items:11,
    onselect: function (obj) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(obj);

        // You still can use the manufacturer_id here 
        console.log(obj.manufacturer_id);

        return obj.manufacturer;
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked after making two corrections. function(typeahead, query) changed to (query, typehead). instead of typeahead.process(manufacturers), gave typeahead(manufacturers);

Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was getting this exact error, and it turned out that the version of Bootstrap I was using (2.0.4) did not support passing in a function to the `source` setting.

Upgrading to Bootstrap 2.1.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: I am using bootstrap v3.1.1 and I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED / REVISED LOOK AT THE ISSUE:**  The error you mentioned "Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" occurred to me when I used the original Typeahead extension in bootstrap that does not support AJAX. (as you have found) Are you sure that the original typeahead extension isn't loading, instead of your revised one?

I have been sucessfully [using this Gist of typeahead](https://gist.github.com/2712048) that is a slight variation on the one you mention. Once I switched to that Gist and confirmed that the input data was good (testing that the input was a string array in an JS object, the issue went away.

Hope this helps

---

Original answer:

The reason the error occurs is because the value passed into the typeahead matcher function is undefined. That is just a side effect to the real issue which occurs somewhere between your input and that matcher function. I suspect the 'manufacturers' array has a problem. Test it first to verify you have a valid array.

```
// It appears your array constructor is missing ()
// try the following in your binding code:
var manufacturers = new Array();
```

Here is what I am using to bind the input to typeahead. I confirmed that it works with your modified typeahead fork.

My HTML:

```
<!-- Load bootstrap styles -->
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...

<input type="text" class="typeahead" name="Category" id="Category" maxlength="100" value="" />

...
<!-- and load jQuery and bootstrap with modified typeahead AJAX code -->
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-modified-typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My binding JavaScript code:

```
// Matches the desired text input ID in the HTML
var $TypeaheadInput = $("#Category");  

// Modify this path to your JSON source URL
// this source should return a JSON string array like the following:
// string[] result = {"test", "test2", "test3", "test4"}
var JsonProviderUrl = "../CategorySearch";

// Bind the input to the typeahead extension
$TypeaheadInput.typeahead({
    source: function (typeahead, query) {
        return $.post(JsonProviderUrl, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return typeahead.process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `new Array` is valid shorthand.  JavaScript doesn't require parenthesis if you are not providing arguments to a constructor.

Comment: I stand corrected on the Array. Looking for something that would cause the data to be undefined... I don't have the ability to duplicate the specific data source, so I'm not certain if there is some other mismatch. I don't believe the typeahead code is an issue, because it is working for me.

Comment: I solved the "Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined" issue by playing around with the loading order of the js scripts (bootstrap, jquery and typeahed).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had null values in my source array causing this error.

Contrived example:

```
source : ["item 1", "item 2", null, "item 4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your manufacturer objects don't have a "name" property, you should change

```
property: 'name',
```

to

```
property: 'manufacturer',
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using mapping variables like example below, you need to use this when you got more then one property in your object;

```
source: function (query, process) {
        states = [];
        map = {};

        var data = [
            {"stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California"},
            {"stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona"},
            {"stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York"},
            {"stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada"},
            {"stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio"}
        ];

        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
            map[state.stateName] = state;
            states.push(state.stateName);
        });

        process(states);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue a while ago. I advice you to recheck configuration where you are including `typeahead` libraries (via main.js, app.js or config.js).

Otherwise, you can overwrite the [latest Bootstrap version](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) to your application library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
var hash = 0;
if (this.length == 0) return hash;
for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    char = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
    hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
}
return hash;
};

var map_manufacter, result_manufacters;
$('#manufacturer').typeahead({
source: function(typeahead, query){
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin+"/bows/get_manufacturers.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function(results){

            result_manufacter = [], map_manufacters = {};
            $.each(results.data.manufacturers, function(item, data){                    
                map_manufacters[data.Manufacturer.manufacturer.hashCode()] = data;
                result_manufacters.push(data.Manufacter.manufacter);
            });             
            typeahead.process(result_manufacters);                
        }
    });
},
property: 'name',
items:11,
onselect: function (obj) {
    var hc = obj.hashCode();
    console.log(map_manufacter[hc]);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem only updating the file bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js to the file in https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js

I think most people can solve this way.