# Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead doesn't process response

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have Spring MVC controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/bla")
public class TestController {       
    @RequestMapping(value = "json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getJson(@ModelAttribute SearchQueryJson searchQueryJson) {
        System.out.println("hih");
        System.out.println(searchQueryJson.getQuery());     
        return new String("{'asd','asdd'}");
    }
}
```

and js:

```
<script>
    $("#searchbox").typeahead({
        source: function (typeahead, query) {
            return $.post("bla/json", { query: query }, function (data) {
                return typeahead.process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

at google chrome debugger i see response {'asd','asdd'}, but nothing happens (dropdown at search box doesn't appears)! i'm using [twitter bootstrap typeahead (method 'toLowerCase' of undefined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235644/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-method-tolowercase-of-undefined) and https://gist.github.com/2712048

Answer (score 1):

change `return typeahead.process(data);`

to `return typeahead(data);`