# PHP: Bootstrap, CodeIgniter - Typeahead data pulling from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, typeahead

I am attempting to query SQL to get an array of values to use for typeahead and I'm apparently missing the fundamentals of arrays because it's not giving me even close to the results that I expect

I want to gather the "Name" column from SQL for distinct data only

Here is my MySQL query

```
$data['typeahead'] = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT Name from table')->result_array();
```

Here is the output it gives on var_dump

```
array(287) { 
 [0]=> array(1) { ["Name"]=> string(16) "'67 Shelby GT500" } 
 [1]=> array(1) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "Tooligan" } 
 [2]=> array(1) { ["Name"]=> string(24) "'67 Pontiac Firebird 400" } 
 [3]=> array(1) { ["Name"]=> string(17) "Volkswagen Beetle" } 
}
```

The only thing I'm trying to do is build an array with the data from the columns. I'm using CodeIgniter for FrameWork and will be using Bootstrap's JS to work with the typeahead, but I'm stuck on the data array section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've found numerous tutorials on how to use non MySQL arrays as typeahead, but none working with MySQL.

^^ Solved

Issue now:

Typeahead isn't pulling data from array

controller code:

```
 $name_array = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT Name from table')->result_array();

 $typeahead_string = '';
 foreach ($name_array as $name)
 {
  $formatted_name    =  '"' . $name['Name'] . '", ';
  $typeahead_string .= $formatted_name;
 }

 $option_list = "[" . rtrim($typeahead_string, ", ") . "]";
 $data['typeahead'] = $option_list;
```

View Code:

```
<input type="text" class="span3 search-query" placeholder="Search" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="<?php echo $typeahead; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object that represents a query result. I know nothing about CI but I'm sure the documentation explains how to make a database query.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario you were correct, I added ->result_array() and now i'm getting an array inside an array. I just need to figure out how to remove the first array completely

Comment: You could try and see what `row_array()` returns instead `result_array()`, or get your array data by using `$newArray = $oldArray[0];`. This simply puts into `$newArray` a first element of `$oldArray` (that first element happens to be an array too).

Comment: row_array gives 1 entry so does $data['typeahead'] = $temp['0'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the results that your query is currently generating and add the `Name` elements to an new array, like this:

```
$name_array = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT Name from HWC')->result_array();

$typeahead_array = array();
foreach ($name_array as $name)
{
    $typeahead_array[] = $name['Name'];
}

$data['typeahead'] = $typeahead_array;
```

---

Edit:

To use the typeahead functionality in Bootstrap, the data source can be a list of strings, for example: `"Orange", "Apple", "Banana"`

You could assign the `$data['typeahead']` variable a string that is a list of options, pass it to the view and echo it to the relevant attribute.

**Controller**

The loop below will create a string variable that will contain all of the options for the typeahead. It adds quotation marks around each element and a comma at the end - so `Apple` would become `"Apple",`. It will then append each element to the string.

```
$name_array = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT Name from HWC')->result_array();

$typeahead_string = '';
foreach ($name_array as $name)
{
    $formatted_name    =  '"' . $name['Name'] . '", ';
    $typeahead_string .= $formatted_name; 
}

$option_list = rtrim($typeahead_string, ",");  //Strips the last comma and any whitespace from the end string

$data['typeahead'] = $option_list;
```

**View**

Your input in the view should look something similar to this, the important part being where the option list is echoed: `data-source="[<?php echo $typeahead; ?>]"`

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="[<?php echo $typeahead; ?>]">
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Now I just have to figure out how to make an array variable work with typeahead. Any thoughts there?

Comment: Hi, @AndrewWilson, I've updated my answer so it should now work with Bootstrap's typeahead.

Comment: with that I get Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Oops, using `rtrim($typeahead_string, ",")` instead (as shown in the edit above), should work.

Comment: the array looks correct with rtrim($typeahead_string, ", "), but it still won't call from typeahead correctly

Comment: What do you mean by won't call correctly? Won't call at all? Or something else? If you edit your question to include the code for the view then that'd be useful :)

Comment: Got it working with JS
     <script>
      $(function(){
       $("#typeahead").typeahead({
        source: <?php echo $typeahead; ?>
       });
      });
     </script>
Thank you!!!! @Lefters

Comment: Also, if you think that there might be a lot of possible options for the typeahead, then it would be worth looking into an Ajax call that would populate the dropdown as it should be more efficient.

Comment: There will probably be around 11,000 entries. I haven't touched AJAX at all, but I know I'll need to with this project. Would it be hard to convert it to AJAX?

Comment: I don't have that much experience with AJAX but I think it'd be fairly easy, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example) should help.

Answer (score 0):

still doesn't work for me. when I inspect elements the data like this " uncategories","php" . what means the first is always spasing.

found the way instead using this `$formatted_name    =  '"' . $name['Name'] . '", ';` just change to `$formatted_name    =  '&quot;' . $name['Name'] . '&quot;, ';`