# how to change the source property of typeahead in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using twitter bootstrap 2.0.4. i want to populate the dropdown using ajax.
the source property of the typeahead plugin requires the value of source to be either an array 
or a function. i tried changing the value of the array after the ajax request but it only displays the results of the first request.

```
<form class="navbar-search">
   <input type="text" id="searchSong" class="typeahead" placeholder="Search">
</form>

 $('.typeahead').keyup(function(){                     
                var list;
                var q = $('.typeahead').val();
                if(!q){
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/WebApplication1/Playlist/search?query="+q,
                    success: function(data){
                        list = data.split(',');
                        alert(list);
                        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                            source: list
                        })
                    }
                });
```

the alert box shows the data loaded from ajax is correct but the dropdown still shows the previous values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that version supports populating typeahead with ajax out-of-the-box. There are versions of the plugin, though, that do support it.

[Here's one](https://github.com/pwarelis/Ajax-Typeahead). I don't remember if that's the same one I'm using, but if it is, it works very well. I'll find out for sure and update this answer.

**Update:**

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example) you should look at. This [extension](https://gist.github.com/1866577) given in the selected answer is the one I use.

Answer (score 3):

You can't re-initialize the plugin if it's already in use.

Try updating the already at work typeahead : [Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ncZJn/)

```
var typeahead = $('.typeahead').data('typeahead');
if(typeahead) typeahead.source = list;
else $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: list});
```

[Plugin code responsible (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L294)

Comment: this doesn't work, it returns 'm getting Cannot set property 'source' of undefined

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek As you can see in the demo, it works with v2. You might be using Bootstrap v3 : if so, the typeahead plugin has been removed in favor of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js)

Answer (score 0):

This has an answer here.

[Update or change typeahead data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814101/update-or-change-typeahead-data)

The way to do this is to use a BloodHound as a source. Whatever the data, remote or local, it is the only way I found to update the source dynamically.

None of the syntax above worked for me but that could be because my typehead search uses multiple sources.

Answer (score -3):

Eat this

```
  $.get('/my_url/' + some_params, function(data){
    $("#address-field").typeahead().data().typeahead.source = data
  },'json');
```

Comment: You should provide more details in your answer. It's probably the right answer but please do elicit it. Thansk.