# How to update the data source in typeahead in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, client-side-scripting, typehead

I have been trying to update the datasouce but not able to do so.

```
   <input  id="supplierNumberSearch" type="text"  />
```

I have code written in JS which are as follows :

```
$('#supplierNumberSearch').typeahead({
        name: 'all-suppliers',
        prefetch: {
            url: '/Supplier/GetAllSuppliersJSON',
            ttl: 0
        },
        template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> - {{text}}</p>',
        engine: Hogan,
        minLength: 0,
        limit: 50,
        highlight: true
    }).on('typeahead:selected', onAutoCompleteSelected)
    .on('typeahead:onTypeAheadComplete', onAutoCompleteSelected);
```

But my datasource doesnt change.

I am taking help from below :

[Update or change typeahead data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814101/update-or-change-typeahead-data)

But I am not able to update the datasouce. Can some one please help

Comment: This helped me... https://tosbourn.com/refreshing-local-data-with-typeahead-js/