# Returning results for bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to return results for the bootstrap typeahead after doing an ajax request, but its not working however it does work when i don't initiate the ajax request.

This does not work:

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/typeahead",
      type: "GET",
      data: "action=" + query,
      success: function(result) {
        return result;  // this returns an array checked with console
      }
    });
  }
});
```

with no ajax it works:

```
  $(".typeahead").typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
          return ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting your ajax URL at all?  If so, verify that the query is what you expect it to be when it gets sent and received.

Comment: @user1477388 yeh im sure because i have checked it with js console :)

Comment: Are you sure that your 'success' event is firing?  Add `console.log('success');` into your 'success' event function and run the script to check.

Comment: @user1477388 yeh its working i checked it by consoling the result inside the success function :)

Comment: Check out the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example

Comment: @unknown are you trying to do anything after getting the data?

Comment: Try removing `return` from `return $.ajax({` The only return line should be `return result;`

Comment: @arjuncc nope thats the only thing im trying to do, is return the result to typeahead :)

Comment: @user1477388 tried that still not working :(

Comment: Then the problem is probably with the data itself.  Can you post the `result` array?  Typically, you have to pass JSON and convert that into an array.  You cant just send an array from the server, I don't think...

Comment: `["abdulsaleh"] ` this is the output to the console`console.log("results")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return process(result) instead of just returning the result.

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "/typeahead",
      type: "GET",
      data: "action=" + query,
      success: function(result) {
        return process(result);  // this returns an array checked with console
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set the ajax call in one function..

```
function typeahead()
    {
    $.ajax({
          url: "/typeahead",
          type: "GET",
          data: "action=" + query,
          success: function(result) {
            return result;  // this returns an array checked with console
          }
        });
    }
```

after initilze u put the code like this

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
         var data=typeahead(query);
         process(data);

      }
    });
```