# Ajax typeahead not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

I am pulling stock symbols from Yahoo finance in a json object and I am trying to show them as a drop-down menu while the user starts typing the name of the company or the symbol in the search box .

Typeahead is not working as a drop down menu from the search box. This is the code I have so far.

If I dump the $data or $result in the suggest.php while substituting {$_POST['symbol']} with goog for example I am getting an array back. So, I am thinking that either suggest.php echo is not returning anything or suggest.php is not being called from the quote.js file.

If I remove the if statement in suggest.php and substitute {$_POST['symbol']} with goog and then go to `http://localhost/suggest.php` shouldn't echo print something?

Any help is appreciated. I am new to web development and trying to learn.

quote.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // create autocomplete
  $('#form-quote input[name=symbol]').typeahead({

      // load autocomplete data from suggest.php
      source: function(query, callback) {
          $.ajax({
              url: '../suggest.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                  symbol: query
              },
              success: function(response) {
                  callback(response.symbols);

              }
          });
      }
  });

  // load data via ajax when form is submitted
  $('#form-quote').on('click', function() {

      // determine symbol
      var symbol = $('#form-quote input[name=symbol]').val();

      // send request to quote.php
      $.ajax({
          url: 'quote.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              symbol: symbol
          },
          success: function(response) {
              $('#price').text(response);
          }
      });


      return false;
  });

});
```

quote.php

```
<?php

//configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

//if form was submitted 

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $stock = lookup(strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]));

    if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){

        //echo "You must enter a stock symbol";

    }else if($_POST["symbol"]){

    $price = number_format($stock['price'], 2);

    echo "A share of {$stock['name']} costs $$price";
    }
}

else{

    // render portfolio
render("stock_search.php", ["title" => "Get Quote"]);
}   
?>
```

quote_search.php

```
<form id = "form-quote" action="quote.php" method="post">
<fieldset>     
    <div class="control-group">
        <input name="symbol" autofocus autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Symbol"  type="text"/>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Get Quote</button>
    </div>

</fieldset>
<div id="price"></div>
<div id="suggestions"></div> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quote.js" ></script>
```

suggest.php

```
 <?php

// configuration
require("../includes/functions.php");

// if form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // load suggestion data
$data = @file_get_contents("http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=  {$_POST['symbol']}&region=US&lang=en-US&callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks");

    // parse yahoo data into a list of symbols
$result = array();
    $json = json_decode(substr($data, strlen('YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks('), -1));
    foreach ($json->ResultSet->Result as $stock)
        $result[] = $stock;

    echo json_encode(array('symbols' => $result]));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some typos. You might want to enable errors in php if this is a test server.

Anyway, from this code:

```
// load suggestion data
$data = @file_get_contents("http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-US&callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks");

// parse yahoo data into a list of symbols
$patt = array("/^YAHOO\.util\.ScriptNodeDataSource\.callbacks\(/","/\)$/");
$repl = array("","");
$json = json_decode(preg_replace($patt,$repl,$data));

foreach ($json->ResultSet->Result as $stock)
    $result[] = $stock;

echo json_encode(array('symbols' => $result));
```

I get the following output:

```
{"symbols":[{"symbol":"GOOG","name":"Google Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"^UVSPY","name":"NASDAQ OMX Alpha GOOG vs. SPY","exch":"NAS","type":"I","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Index"},{"symbol":"GOOG-U.TI","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"TLO","type":"S","exchDisp":"TLX Exchange ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOG11BF.SA","name":"GOOGLE -DRN MB","exch":"SAO","type":"S","exchDisp":"Sao Paolo","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOG.MX","name":"Google Inc.","exch":"MEX","type":"S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GOOF.EX","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"EUX","type":"S","exchDisp":"EUREX Futures and Options Exchange ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.F","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"FRA","type":"S","exchDisp":"Frankfurt","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.MU","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"MUN","type":"S","exchDisp":"Munich","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.HA","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"HAN","type":"S","exchDisp":"Hanover","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GGQ1.DE","name":"GOOGLE-A","exch":"GER","type":"S","exchDisp":"XETRA","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}
```

With your data fetching and parsing corrected, if you are using Bootstrap 2.1+ you should be able to implement the ajax call to your PHP proxy as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156734/1072176). (Search the page for "Bootstrap 2.1" if the link doesn't jump down to it.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do get the same results as you. Is there a way to check if the ajax function is working right? I still cannot get the drop-down menu.

Comment: Update? You said I fixed the PHP output, but you didn't accept my answer. Did you update your ajax call per the answer I linked to?

Comment: I get the results with your changes but when I i try to get the results from ajax I still cannot get the drop-down menu.