# Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 together with where go Typeahead?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

Currently **twitter.github.io/bootstrap/‎** redirect to **getbootstrap.com/**, which contains Bootstrap 3.

This version does not have typeahead.js package.

Does anyone know why? I don't see any post mentioning about this.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903645/where-is-the-typeahead-javascript-module-in-bootstrap-3-rc-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, They dropped it from the bootstrap project because the moved it into its very own project. Its no longer 'underneath' bootstrap, but you can still get an updated version. The standalone project is now hosted https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/