# bootstrap 3 typeahead wont show results

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to implement  typeahead  in mvc 4.

(i included the the typeahead  js and css.)

Im using this ajax method in order to get the list

```
$(function() {
         // get your list
         $.getJSON('/Main/GetServiceNames', function (allData) {
             $('#servicename').typeahead({source: allData});
         });
     });
```

This is the result of the ajax request :

```
["RetrieveDocument","PublishDocument","PublishFeedback","PublishSurvey","RetrievePartner","RetrieveLabelDocuments","RPCRetrieveZipCode","ESB2InfraService","PublishTest","PublishPolcy"]
```

But for some reason the result wont bind to the **#servicename**  Html input
This is the html that im trying to bind to and none of the list is shown.

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="servicename" id="servicename" data-provide="typeahead">
```

EDIT:
i managed to create the same error here [typeahead fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/miko5054/J2924/)

thanks

miki

Comment: I though the typeahead plugin was removed in Bootstrap 3..? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17904021/651789

Comment: i added typeahead.js  by myself   https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/
and the typeahead css to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example [here](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation#typeahead). Also, keep in mind that **Bootstra's typeahead.js** is different from **Twitter's typeahead.js**, which I think you are using. You can get Bootstrap's typeahead.js [here](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Scripts/bootstrap.typeahead.js).