# bootstrap-tagsinput with typeahead, bootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, twitter-typeahead, jquery-tags-input

In a project of mine I used to have bootstrap-tagsinput http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput along bootstrap-2.3.2. Recently I've updated both (bootstrap to 3, and tagsinput to 0.3.9). During the update I found out that tagsinput externally depends on http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/.

I tried to use bs-tagsinput with typeahead according to the docs. That was a bit bumpy. For example the typeahead code sample under bootstrap-tagsinput docs:

```
$('input').tagsinput('input').typeahead({
  prefetch: 'citynames.json'
}).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {  
  this.tagsinput('add', datum.value);
  this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
}, $('input')));
</script>
```

**typeahead['setQuery']** no longer exists in typeahead ver 1.0 (it does in ver 0.9). I use the typeahead.source method for the dataset. typeahead from 'source' is not implemented in 0.9 so downgrading does not seem like an option. I wasn't sure if to replace it with typeahead['val'] or not (though, both didn't fix the issues I was seeing).
As for CSS, I copied it from the bootstrap-tagsinput docs page -- not sure this was the intention (I'm a newb so I don't know better).

The problem is that after putting everything together, I bumped into buggy behavior (as expected). Specifically I'm facing a problem where after inserting a tag (typing a word and pressing enter): 
(1) the tt-dropdown-menu should disappear but it does not. It sticks around along with the previous tt-suggestions list
and 
(2) the tt-hint field should be cleared but is not

It could be useful to mention that this problem does not occur if I use the arrows to select one of the tt-suggestions

Anyone knows whats the best way to get back the tagsinput-w/typeahead functionality?

Comment: try "this.tagsinput('input').typeahead('val', '');" instead of setQuery for clearing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I've found the answer here:
[Where is the typeahead JavaScript module in Bootstrap 3 RC 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903645/where-is-the-typeahead-javascript-module-in-bootstrap-3-rc-1)

To make a long story short, looks like bootstrap-tagsinput and typeahead.js 1.0 just don't play well because of css/other incompatibilities.

This project https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead (thanku @bassjobsen) solved it for me. It backports bootstrap-typeahead from 2.3.2 into bootstrap-3 (the API is unchanged) and so far it works well with bootstrap-tagsinput!

Comment: How do you call typeahead from tagsinput?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly, I used bootstrap-tagsinput as is and it just worked out of the box

Comment: I've got it working. Thanks for the response. I think it works when you use the example from Bootstrap 2. I was trying the example from Bootstrap 3 with the typeahead you linked.

Comment: Ah yes. Since bootstrap-tagsinput is backported, it needs to be used the same way as if using it in bootstrap-2.3.2

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/40. You can use `$('.typeahead').tagsinput({typeahead :
{
source: ["Alabama","Alaska"]
}});`

Comment: Worked fine after I included Typeahead for BS3 before Tagsinput:) Thanks guys!:)

Answer (score 5):

The **twitter.github.io/typeahead.js** not compatible with bootstrap 3.

You can use this **Typeahead** which is compatible with twitter bootstrap 3

https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Actually the developer migrated bootstrap 2 code in to bootstrap 3 here is the details http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/migrate-your-templates-from-twitter-bootstrap-2-x-to-twitter-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Excelent, i was using the typeahead only with bootstrap and was not working.