# Typeahead.js v0.10.1 and Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I have just updated to the most recent version of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to get access to some new features.  It is not compatible with [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/).  With the previous version (pre Bloodhound.js) I had to add custom CSS that I found in forums that made it compatible.  This CSS it not working with the most recent update.

Does anyone know where I can get the CSS for bootstrap 3 / typeahead.js v0.10.1?

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmatt2/7n6Hv/4/)

```
<Satisfy-StackOverflow-Code-Requirement-For-Links-to-jsfiddle>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the typeahead javascript module in bootstrap 3 RC 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903645/where-is-the-typeahead-javascript-module-in-bootstrap-3-rc-1)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with that, Typeahead c0.10.1 was released on 2nd Feb 14

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, I managed to get it working with the following css

```
.twitter-typeahead {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
 }

.tt-dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.tt-suggestion {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0081c2;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor a {
    color: #fff;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

### UPDATE for typeahead.js v0.11.1

```
/**********************************************************
 *     typeahead.js v0.11.1 - twitter bootstrap v3.3.5    *
 **********************************************************/

/*root typeahead class*/
.twitter-typeahead {
    display: inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[disabled] {
  background-color : #eeeeee !important;
}

/*Added to input that's initialized into a typeahead*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input {

}

/*Added to hint input.*/
.twitter-typeahead .hint {

}

/*Added to menu element*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;

  -moz-box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
  box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
}

/*Added to dataset elements*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-dataset {

}

/*dded to suggestion elements*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/*Added to menu element when it contains no content*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-empty {
  background-color: white;
}

/*Added to menu element when it is opened*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-open {
  background-color: white;
}

/*Added to suggestion element when menu cursor moves to said suggestion*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:hover,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:focus,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-cursor {
  cursor: hand !important;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  color: white;
}

/*Added to the element that wraps highlighted text*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-highlight {

}
```

Comment: For typeahead.js 0.11.1 I just replaced .tt-dropdown-menu with .tt-menu. Thanks.

Comment: @jax looked around and your solution was the best for me.  It really works.  Thanks!

Comment: Like a boss! Love it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `scss` version:

```
@mixin typeahead-active() {
  // mimics  @extend .dropdown-menu > .active > a;
  color: $dropdown-link-active-color;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: $dropdown-link-active-bg;
}

//https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#class-names
span.twitter-typeahead {

  // this is the suggested matches dropdown
  .tt-menu {
    @extend .dropdown-menu;
  }

  .tt-hint {
    color: #999
  }

  // Added to suggestion elements.
  .tt-suggestion {

    // mimic .dropdown-menu > li > a
    padding: 3px 20px;
    line-height: $line-height-base;

    // Added to suggestion element when menu cursor moves to said suggestion.
    &.tt-cursor {
      @include typeahead-active;
    }

    // Hover/focus on suggestion
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      @include typeahead-active;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }

  .input-group & {
    display: block !important;
    .tt-dropdown-menu {
      top: 32px !important;
    }
  }
  .input-group.input-group-lg & {
    .tt-dropdown-menu {
      top: 44px !important;
    }
  }
  .input-group.input-group-sm & {
    .tt-dropdown-menu {
      top: 28px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweetness! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The update proposed by @jax is the best solution I find after lot of hours.

I have needed make some modifications on original CSS to work correctly with BS 3.3.6. Here it is:

```
/**********************************************************
 *     typeahead.js v0.11.1 - twitter bootstrap v3.3.6    *
 **********************************************************/

/*root typeahead class*/
span.twitter-typeahead {
    width: 100%;
}
.input-group span.twitter-typeahead {
    display: block !important;
}

.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[disabled] {
    background-color : #eeeeee !important;
}

/*Added to input that's initialized into a typeahead*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
}

/*Added to hint input.*/
.twitter-typeahead .hint {
}

/*Added to menu element*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
    box-shadow: 12px 14px 30px -7px #616161;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
        width: 200%;
    }
}

.input-group .twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
    margin-top: 32px;
}

.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
    margin-top: 44px;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
    margin-top: 28px;
}

/*Added to dataset elements*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-dataset {

}

/*Added to suggestion elements*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/*Added to menu element when it contains no content*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-empty {
    background-color: white;
}

/*Added to menu element when it is opened*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-open {
    background-color: white;
}

/*Added to suggestion element when menu cursor moves to said suggestion*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:hover,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:focus,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-cursor {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: white;
}

/*Added to the element that wraps highlighted text*/
.twitter-typeahead .tt-highlight {

}
```