# Dropdown menu with text input filter at the top of the options?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen a component being used where you have a select menu, and when you drop down the options, there is a text input at the top. You can type in there to filter the select menu's options.

Unfortunately, I can't remember where I saw this, and I don't know what this type of component is called.

I am looking to do this with Bootstrap 3, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of a plugin such as [**Select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) (or its predecessor, **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**). Bootstrap had Typeahead in version 2, but **[it's apparently been dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903645/where-is-the-typeahead-javascript-module-in-bootstrap-3-rc-1)** in favor of Bootstrap's **[standalone Typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)**.