# Xpages: TypeAhead with Twitter Bootstrap - Loading a SSJS Array into the value list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-notes, bootstrap-typeahead

i was trying to add  BootsTrap Typeahead to one of my Xpages. So i imported all the Bootstrap stuff to my application. 
When i put the values "hardcoded" into the list, it works perfectly. But i created an array of "Values" in a SSJS Library.

Can you tell me how i can put that array from the SSJS Lib to the value list of typeahead?

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" styleClass="typeahead"></xp:inputText>

<script>
var value = ['test', 'birthday']
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source: value });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typeahead component has been [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903645/where-is-the-typeahead-javascript-module-in-bootstrap-3-rc-1) in Bootstrap 3 in favour of Twitter's typeahead library. It does work in Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Anyway. You'll need to use an `xp:scriptBlock` control to be able to reference server side variables. My first reaction would be to do this:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
  <![CDATA[
   #{javascript:viewScope.put("typeaheadOptions", ["Alabama", "Alaska"] );}
  ]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    styleClass="typeahead"></xp:inputText>

<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
      var value = #{viewScope.typeaheadOptions};
      $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: value });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

But that didn't work: you will end up with javascript that look like this:

```
var value = [Alabama, Alaska];
```

Notice the missing quotes around the entries.

To solve that you can wrap the variable in a `toJson` function before storing it.

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
  <![CDATA[
   #{javascript:viewScope.put("typeaheadOptions", toJson(["Alabama", "Alaska"]) );}
  ]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Comment: THX, that was what I´m searching for. But is there a possibility that when i have an array with multiple Strings in it, that i can give the complete array to the viewScope variable like that:

viewScope.put("typeaheadOptions", toJson([array]) )

or must i use

viewScope.put("typeaheadOptions", toJson([array[0], array[1]) )

Thx for your help

Comment: I have solved it:
var stringArray = array.toString();
var values= stringArray.split(",");
viewScope.put("typtypeaheadOptionseAheadValues", toJson(values));