# Bootstrap TypeAhed Data via Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

How I can Get data-provide using example.php in which Results Categories comes from Mysql Database using Ajax

```
<input class="span4" id="sasa" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Mobile","Books","Electonics","Food","Magazine"]'>
```

Search

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example) will help

Comment: How I can use php File data

Comment: Create array and encode it using `encode_json` and echo it...