# Simpliq Bootstrap Typeahead with MySQL data

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

So I'm using the Simpliq theme for Bootstrap, and it has a typeahead component in the form.
It requires that I use a "data-source" field with an array of values.  Unfortunately, the dataset I have is in the hundreds, and it will substantially slow down page loading, if not time it out completely.

My question is, is there a data-remote or something I could use to fetch data-set based on entered term in the text field without having to use a "data-source" array?  I don't want to place the whole data-set in the typeahead field.

I'm using MySQL to fetch the field "property_no" from three different tables, each with their hundred rows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead, source can also be configured (manually) to be a function and

> The function may be used synchronously by returning the data source
>   directly or asynchronously via the process callback's single argument.

And this SO question shows you how exactly to get the options asynchronously - [twitter bootstrap typeahead ajax example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example)