# PHP AJAX Live Search textbox dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm using Live Search in PHP Form using AJAX

[image: Current Output]

Above image is using DIV id to display results from ajax call.

How can I display results under textbox like screenshot attached::

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: you need to design and position that div with css.

Comment: I'm new to this, can you help if you've any reference link or something

Comment: I'm using bootstrap, so if there is any existing class which can work, then please let me know

Comment: you should use typeahead.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example